# Cloudflare HTTPS subdomain to Cloudfront/S3-bucket gives 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Cloudflare for my DNS and have SSL full.
I'm trying to set up a subdomain; https://humlor.myrenas.se and point that to an AWS S3-bucket. I have Set up Cloudfront with a Default CloudFront Certificate (*.cloudfront.net) and the site is available at https://d2ufhnw2kk1vh9.cloudfront.net/ (without styling of some absolute paths to the CSS)

I have then created a CNAME record in Cloudflare: CNAME
humlor  is an alias of d2ufhnw2kk1vh9.cloudfront.net

But https://humlor.myrenas.se/ gives:
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request.

Do I need another certificate in Cloudfront? Or what is missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error message almost always means the request did arrive at CloudFront, but that CloudFront does not recognize the hostname that was contained in the HTTP headers.  This suggests that you overlooked the need to set the **Alternate Domain Name** in your CloudFront distribution.

> If you want to use your own domain name, such as `www.example.com`, instead of the `cloudfront.net` domain name that CloudFront assigned to your distribution, you can add an alternate domain name to your distribution for `www.example.com`.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

By default, CloudFlare doesn't change the `Host` header the browser sends, so CloudFront sees your custom domain name in the incoming request, and doesn't know what to do next, because no configured distribution has this name configured as an Alternate Domain Name, so it returns this error.

Answer (score -2):

For "https://humlor.myrenas.se and point that to an AWS S3-bucket": you need route53, by which your URL will be able to point to the s3 bucket (name of the s3 bucket should be humlor.myrenas.se also)

you don't need cloudfront when you got cloud flare...

Your DNS to be on cloud flare, where you map your URL to AWS IP --- AWS route53 takes this URL and points to your s3 bucket and the default page there shows up

Comment: Route53 isn't needed here, and you can't use both Route53 and CloudFlare DNS at the same time anyway.

Comment: @Mark, No way to point to an s3 bucket without route53... I have been using cloud flare to route53 to my s3 bucket for years, cloud flare is also a CDN... Check yourself at Akberiqbal.com

Comment: Yes I understand CloudFlare is also a CDN, but to use CloudFlare CDN you also have to use CloudFlare as your DNS host. You can point CloudFlare directly to the S3 bucket's generic URL. There is no need to configure a custom DNS name for the S3 bucket and no need to use Route53.

Comment: You cannot point CNAME directly to S3 over SSL. S3 is only http.

Comment: Generic name for the s3 bucket would work, but for questooner wants a specific URL: my answer reflects what that. Cloud flare helped me get a free HTTPS also; the only cost for my AWS is because of the route53 which I needed for my s3... Else AWS λ and Api gateway handles the load brilliantly

Comment: You can do CNAME to the generic name of the s3 bucket... Need route53 for a specific URL

Comment: S3 and Cloudfront is connected and works on https://d2ufhnw2kk1vh9.cloudfront.net/

Comment: @Akber Iqbal are you not using Cloudfront at all? Only S3 and Route53?

Comment: Yup, no cloud front... Cloud flare for CDN, for HTTPS... At the back I got s3, λ and Api gateway... Running a scalable setup for akberiqbal.com